# Delete item on ListView after click delete button on ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I wrote a code to display images, button & texts dynamically in a ListView.
So ListView load the button. I want to delete the selected item in ListView by clicking this button.

Adapter class:

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoaderLogoUnder imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoaderLogoUnder(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflatelistview, null);

        TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button btn=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setTag(position);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Integer index = (Integer) v.getTag();
                //items.remove(index.intValue());  
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
        text.setText("item "+position);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

This is a ListView Activity class

```
ShowData show = new ShowData();

        String s[] = show.getData();
        adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, s);

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try using `ArrayList` instead as below:

```
 public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<String> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoaderLogoUnder imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<String> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoaderLogoUnder(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflatelistview, null);

    TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button btn=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setTag(position);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Integer index = (Integer) v.getTag();
            //items.remove(index.intValue());  
            data.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
    text.setText("item "+position);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data.get(position), image);
    return vi;
}
}
```

Comment: How to find out after deletion in the activity

Answer (score 1):

1. remove the item from "data".
2. call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 1):

Your commented-out section in the OnClick listener looks like you are almost there. I would change the type of your data d element from an array of strings to an ArrayList (from *private String[] data* to *private ArrayList data*). This will make for easier removal of the item you want gone.

Removal of an item from a simple [] array is more work, you basically have to create a new array and repopulate with the items to keep, return the new array. It doesn't have a "remove" method like ArrayList. The adapter class also doesn't have an "items" member, you have to manipulate the "data" member.

Then change the signature of your adapter constructor to *LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList d)*. Change your "remove" line from *items.remove(index.intValue())* to *data.remove(position).* You don't need *btn.setTag* or the *v.getTag* as position is already available. The call to *NotifyDataSetChanged()* will refresh the listview.

The different constructor will mean you need to send an ArrayList into your adapter. *Show.getData()* will need to be changed to return an ArrayList, the type of s will need to change from String[] to ArrayList.

This is essentially the same answer that was given, a little more verbose. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View row = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_result_details_row, parent, false);

        // inflate other items here : 
        Button deleteButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.Details_Button01);
         deleteButton.setTag(position);

        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Integer index = (Integer) view.getTag();
                    items.remove(index.intValue());  
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        );
```

In the getView() method you tag the ListItem to postion

```
deleteButton.setTag(position);
```

Convert the getTag() Object to an Integer

In the OnClickListener() you then delete the item

```
items.remove(index.intValue());
```